# Kinect v1 keeps disconnecting on Windows 10

Tags: xbox360, kinect

I have an xbox360 kinect v1. I want to use it for motion capture. I installed everything. Drivers, software. I tried some motion capture. It worked for 20 seconds and then it disconnected. It kept disconnecting and reconnectiong without stopping. I restart my PC, reinstalled drivers, software. Nothing worked. What to do? :( My USB controller is intel

Comment: It works on my XBox

Comment: Yes. I got it working. but after 2 minutes of use it disconnects again